# FileNotFoundException when I use FileInputStream

Tags: java, android

In my Android app, the user has to select a picture on the phone that he wants to upload on a server.
I retrieve the path but when I initialize a FileInputStream object, I've got an error.

Here is my code:

```
File file = new File(imageURI.getPath());
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
```

I've got this error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /external/images/media/30732: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

However the file exists because the user could select it.

In the manifest, there is the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission. So the problem doesn't come from it.

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

You have a [content Uri](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentUris.html), log it to see it.
`getPath` returns the path part of the `Uri` which has nothing to do with file paths.

Try using:

```
InputStream imageStream = getContext().getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageURI);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for the existence of a file before accessing it.

```
if (file.exists()){

}
```